# update date (datepicker) in useState using onChange in an array of objects in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-hooks

I have used hooks like so:

```
const [tableRows, settableRows] = useState([
    {
        vehicleNumber: '3080',
        bookedOn: '11-23-2019',
        checkIn: new Date()
    },{
        vehicleNumber: '3080',
        bookedOn: '11-23-2019',
        checkIn: new Date()
    }
  ])
```

I have rendered each object using `map` method and have `Datepicker` in `checkin`. I want to change the value of `checkIn` using `onChange`

Answer (score 1):

From what `onChange` you want to change the `checkIn` parameter? you can change your data structure to be an object of objects and set a key related to the `vehicleNumber` (or any unique id) to each object so  you can access the object that you want to modify easily , lets say:

```
const [tableRows, settableRows] = useState({
    `3080`: {
        vehicleNumber: '3080',
        bookedOn: '11-23-2019',
        checkIn: new Date()
    },
    `3081`{
        vehicleNumber: '3081',
        bookedOn: '11-23-2019',
        checkIn: new Date()
    }
  ])
```

and to access with you can write a method like this:

```
const changeCheckIn = ( vehicleNumber ) => {
   const tableRows_ = tableRows;
   tableRows_[vehicleNumber].checkIn = new Date();
   settableRows(tableRows_)
}
```

If you can't modify your data structure you have to send an id to the `changeCheckIn method, so you will be able to identify what row you want to change`by iterating through your list.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for this function

```
const dateChange = index => e => {

    let newArr = [...tableRows]; 
    newArr[index].checkIn = e

    settableRows(newArr);
}
```